# Class won't populate in Identity Inspector Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, class

I'm having a repeating problem in Xcode and would like to ask for help/advice.

Have been creating a new class, FirstViewController, which is a subclass of UIViewController. When I go to the Identity Inspector to layout the .xib file, so that I can layout my objects and make my connections.

But FirstViewController doesn't show up in the dropdown list for Custom Class in Identity Inspector.

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to clean and rebuild project, highlight File owner and then choose Custom Class, restart Xcode, and restart my computer... but to no avail!

Comment: What object have you selected in the document? That is, which object's identity is the Identity inspector inspecting?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I am fairly new to Xcode so I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  I am trying to assign a view controller to a class "FirstViewController"

Comment: Its a bug in Xcode 7, sometimes in Storyboard on any item you click Inspectors in right side pane won't show anythings, Welcome to Xcode update :P

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

One possibility is that you don't have your ViewController's File's Owner selected when you open up your Identity Inspector. Example:

[image]

Notice how Custom Class in Identity Inspector is blank! And I just created FirstViewController and checked the "create XIB" box. What gives? Well on the left I have the UIView selected instead of file's owner.

Now look at this:

[image]

This time I have file's owner selected on the left. And now on the right Custom Class in Identity Inspector says it's FirstViewController.

If you select file's owner in Interface Builder then go to the Identity Inspector there you'll find your class that you want to connect to your VC.

To see this list on the left make sure to click the button that expands this window. It's right here:

[image]

Comment: First off, thank you for the precise answer.  However, on my screen I don't have a "placeholder" category, it just lists out all my "scenes" or view controllers.

Comment: There's a little button at the bottom of Interface Builder that looks like a box with a bar at the side. Click that and it should expand the window?

Comment: Ok so in that case your file's owner would be selected by clicking on Root View Controller with the yellow circle. Mine said "placeholders" because I was on a singular xib. I didn't realize you were really using storyboards (as shown in your linked image).

Comment: I followed all instructions as you mentioned.  I had the Root View Controller with the yellow circle highlighted.  But once I check for the Custom Class in the Identity  Inspector, it still wasn't there!

Comment: And this is how I have it in my actual Viewcontroller.swift file

Comment: class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

Answer (score 0):

In general what you do is this:

1. Drag an instance of your custom object's parent class into the
   XIB/Storyboard.
2. Go to the identity inspector, select the "Class"
   entry, and type your custom class name there. It should auto-fill
   the class name for you.

(Note that this is an Xcode/IB question, and in no way specific to Swift.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with me was that the storyboard view was a table view controller , but the class does not inherit from the UIViewController .

**Just make sure that your view has the right inheritance class as the same storyboard view .**